# Finding the radius with chord length

Tags: geometry, circles

I'm struggling to find the radius of the circle in the image (the only other given length is the length between B and the right angle below, which is 5). Is it even possible to get the radius without knowing any other dimensions? Or is there a way to find it? I've tried to use Pythagoras but without knowing the length of the side of the triangle going towards O, it was hard to find it. 
[image]

Comment: Where have the 2.8s come from in your diagram?

Comment: It was given in the problem, where they asked to get the angle that I marked as theta.

Comment: Just to clarify then, everything in the diagram you provided is from the question itself?

Comment: Yes I think so.The only information that I didn't put was 5 m (between point B and the right angle below it).

Comment: Well I'm almost done, just need to find the angle PBO, if you have any ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to find $\theta$ or the radius from the given data. To see why, imagine to move point $P$ to the left on the horizontal line and let $O$ be the center of circle $ABP$: all given lengths would stay the same, but $r$ and $\theta$ would change.

[image]

Comment: This seems to be the problem posed by Regiomontanus. It has sense if he wants the radius for the greatest visual angle.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of that.The angle of course is maximum when the radius is minimum, that is when the circle is tangent to the base line ($r=7,8$ m).

Comment: Does that mean that the radius would be 7 or 8 m when the angle is maximized?

Comment: Sorry, I should have written $r=7.8$ m. That is: when the circle is tangent, the radius is equal to the distance of $O$ from the baseline.